# Help changing image based on button press

Tags: iphone

I have a problem that I still haven't been able to solve... What I'm trying to create is this: A UIImage on the main view controller. This UIImage needs to be controlled by buttons on the main view controller's subview. So when the button "banana" is pressed, the image on the first view will change to a banana. When the button "apple" is pressed, the image on the first view will change to an apple. When the button "Guava" is pressed, the image on the first view will change to a picture of a guava. The main thing i'm having trouble with is linking the buttons to the UIImage. Also, I'm not sure how to implement the switch mechanism. I also dont know if its better to create an array with the images in them, that the first view can retrieve. Any code/advice would be helpful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

You need to have a responder(s) in your viewcontroller that is linked to all the button(s) on the viewcontroller through interface builder. In IB, to link a button to a method make sure the method is in your viewcontroller.h file and also implemented in the .m file. Then go to the connections panel in IB (after clicking on the button) and drag a connection from 'Touch Up Inside' (touch up inside is when a user touches the button and releases that touch  up and inside the button's boundary) to the viewcontroller.xib window onto the file's owner icon. From there you will be presented with a drop down menu that will let you choose the IBAction methods you specified in the header file.

In this case take:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender; // header file



- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender { // .m file
   // when the button is pressed then change the uiimageview
   [imageView image: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: @"image.png"]];
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the buttons are on a subview of the image, not on the same view that the images are on. What I don't know how to do is make it so when the button is pressed, the image on the previous view will change. With the code you gave me above, it seems like it will work if everything was on on view. However, I have two views. Do I have to import the subviews methods in the main views implementation file? not exactly sure exactly what I have to do to connect buttons to images when theyre on different views. Ive read about callbacks, but Im not sure if that applies to this situation

Comment: @Kevin Fox, sorry I just found your comment. You need to set up delegate functions on your second view that the first view can implement. Then you will be able to do what you want. If you don't know about delegate functions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well @kevin fox i think you are quite new to iphone programming.

what you have to do is create a function like this

```
- (IBAction)changeImagesWithName:(id) sender;
```

in ur header file and implement it in your .m file.

in the IB control drag the buttons to the files owner and click on that method.

Create an instance of uiimageview in your viewcontroller using IBOutlet and connect that to the UIImageView in the IB.

in the above method use something like this

> UIButton *temp = sender;
>
> [imageView image: [UIImage
>   imageNamed:[NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",
>   temp.currentTitle]]];

and name the images to the title of
the buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you have different button for image then use the code given by Michael Dillon

**EDIT : You can hardcode the image name if you have different button for each**

If you have a single button then use array of image and show the next index image on every click